# jQuery Filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering

Is there a way to filter a multi-line select box using jQuery?

I'm a new to jQuery and can't seem to figure out the best way to do this.

For example if I have:

```
<select size="10">
   <option>abc</option>
   <option>acb</option>
   <option>a</option>
   <option>bca</option>
   <option>bac</option>
   <option>cab</option>
   <option>cba</option>
   ...
</select>
```

I want to filter this list based on a selection drop down with:

```
<select>
   <option value="a">Filter by a</option>
   <option value="b">Filter by b</option>
   <option value="c">Filter by c</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this might do the trick (assuming you give your 'Filter by...' select an id of **filter** and the filtered / other select an id of **otherOptions**):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#filter').change(function() {
        var selectedFilter = $(this).val();
        $('#otherOptions option').show().each(function(i) {
            var $currentOption = $(this);
            if ($currentOption.val().indexOf(selectedFilter) !== 0) {
                $currentOption.hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

UPDATE: As @Brian Liang pointed out in the comments, you might have problems setting the <option> tags to **display:none**. Therefore the following should give you a better cross-browser solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var allOptions = {};

    $('#otherOptions option').each(function(i) {
        var $currentOption = $(this);
        allOptions[$currentOption.val()] = $currentOption.text();
    });

    $('#filter').change(function() {
        // Reset the filtered select before applying the filter again
        setOptions('#otherOptions', allOptions);
        var selectedFilter = $(this).val();
        var filteredOptions = {};

        $('#otherOptions option').each(function(i) {
            var $currentOption = $(this);

            if ($currentOption.val().indexOf(selectedFilter) === 0) {
                filteredOptions[$currentOption.val()] = $currentOption.text();
            }
        });

        setOptions('#otherOptions', filteredOptions);
    });

    function setOptions(selectId, filteredOptions) {
        var $select = $(selectId);
        $select.html('');

        var options = new Array();
        for (var i in filteredOptions) {
            options.push('<option value="');
            options.push(i);
            options.push('">');
            options.push(filteredOptions[i]);
            options.push('</option>');
        }

        $select.html(options.join(''));
    }

});
```

Comment: I don't think this works since you cannot hide that option element.

Comment: @Brian Liang I did do a quick test in Firefox before I posted and it worked. However I have just checked in Opera, Safari, Chrome and IE 8 and you're right: it does not work in those browsers.

Comment: Tim, I tried it in Chrome/IE and it works like a charm. Great work Ian!